# Thread.sleep(time) vs. robot.wait(time)

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, awtrobot, fest

I'm trying to write some GUI and integration tests using JUnit and FEST.
Here is what I have:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    try{
        program.main(args);
        robot.wait(30000);    //gives IllegalMonitorStateException
        Thread.sleep(30000);  //no Exception occurs here
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`robot` and `args` are already initialized.

Why do I get such an exception when I call `wait`? Why I don't get the same exception when I call `sleep`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling [`Object.wait()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) - which is *not* the same as [`Thread.sleep()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29). In particular:

- `wait()` requires that you already own the monitor on the object you call it on
- `wait()` allows the thread to be notified (via `Object.notify`/`notifyAll`) and wake up early; `Thread.sleep()` would require the thread to be interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

the `wait()` method is used in conjunction with the `notify()` method to synchronize threads. It is **not** used to delay in a given thread for some amount of time.

You get that exception because in order to `wait()` on a thread, you must have taken that thread's monitor first (via some kind of `synchronized` block or method).

Use `Thread.sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for

```
robot.delay(...);
```

Comment: I'm using [FEST](http://easytesting.org/swing/apidocs/index.html) to access the robot. Does it matter which one I use?

Comment: Ah, FEST has a different [Robot](http://easytesting.org/swing/apidocs/org/fest/swing/core/Robot.html) API than java.awt.[Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)